# How's $dS(y)$ different from $dy$ really?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How's $dS(y)$ different from $dy$ really?

Since the Mean Value Property for a harmonic function is:

$$u(x)=\unicode{x2a0d} \space u(y)dS(y)=\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|} \int_{\partial B(x,r)} u(y) dy$$

Is $dS(y)$ somehow different from $dy$?

Or perhaps it means that one includes the $\frac{1}{|\partial B(x,r)|}$ constant to the $dy$ in order to get $dS(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the surface of a ball is an "$n-1$ dimensional object" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So $dS(y)$ means you take the surface measure, while $dy$ just means that you take the classical $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. The dash through the integral means "mean value", so you divide by the measure of the set you integrate over, in this case $|\partial B(x,r)|$. So in general, you define 
$$
\unicode{x2a0d}_Afdy=\frac{1}{|A|} \int_A fdy
$$
or, for surface integrals:
$$
\unicode{x2a0d}_{\partial A}fdS(y)=\frac{1}{|\partial A|} \int_{\partial A} fdS(y)
$$
The surface measure is taking the $n-1$ dimensional measure of an "$n-1$ dimensional set" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Usually, given a nice parmaterisation $\phi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, you get the following identity:
$$
\int_U f(\phi)\sqrt{det(D\phi^T D\phi)} \space dy^{n-1}=\int_A f \space dS(y)
$$
So lets take $n=2$ and we just take the circle with radius $r$, i.e. the set of points such that $x^2+y^2=r^2$. Then we got a good parameterisation in $\phi: [0, 2 \pi] \to A, \psi \to (r \sin(\psi), r \cos(\psi))$. Then, $det(D\phi^T D \phi)=r^2$ and we get that 
$$
\int_{x^2+y^2=r^2}1 dS(x,y)=\int_0^{2 \pi}r d\psi=2r \pi
$$
In general, you are looking for integration on manifolds.

Comment: Can you clarify what the $dS(y)$ could be? E.g. in the case of a ball? What's a surface measure?

Comment: Also, how does it change the evaluation of the integral?

Comment: I edited my response with a short example. I can not cover a whole course in measure theory though :(

Comment: Knowing what a surface measure is not particularly important, just saying it’s an integral with respect to the surface of your domain is sufficient.

Comment: Thats a reaonable point there! Thinking about it, i cant even recall the last time I calculated such an integral explicitly. Its just important to know that all the properties of an integral hold for those integrals was well.